# Webpack typescript import is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, compilation

I'm bundling this single class with webpack, however when I import it in my project it says that it is undefined. I've been trying a couple of things but I'm just not getting it right.

> myclass.ts

```
export class Dyn {

    abc: any;

    constructor(drawCallback, options?) {

    }

    text(a){
        this.abc = a;
        console.log(this.abc);
    }
}
```

> ts.config

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./src2/js",
        "declaration": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "declarationDir": "./src2/@types",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src2/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

> webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src2/myclass.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "myclass.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },
    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    //devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [
            ".ts"
        ]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            /*{
                enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader"
            },*/

        ],
    },
    // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
    externals: {    
    },
};
```

> myclass.js (webpack result)

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // identity function for calling harmony imports with the correct context
/******/    __webpack_require__.i = function(value) { return value; };
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var Dyn = (function () {
    function Dyn(drawCallback, options) {
    }
    Dyn.prototype.text = function (a) {
        this.abc = a;
        console.log(this.abc);
    };
    return Dyn;
}());
exports.Dyn = Dyn;


/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

> import { Dyn } from 'myclass'; //<<< undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

> libraryTarget: "umd"

to the output part in webpack.config.js fixes this issue